# How can i disable Skype icon from my page?

Tags: html, css, skype

How can i disable the Skype icon that appears next to my phone numbers that i posted in my page?

Comment: Uninstall the plugin in your configuration?

Comment: Have you considered Googling `How can i disable Skype icon from my page?`

Comment: @Bondye: Uninstalling is not a solution because i don't want to crack my design on a customers page. I can't put him to disable his plugin.

Comment: @Pekka웃: the first thing was to google it and i didn't find any solution beside uninstalling it.

Comment: @Dan the link I posted above was the third Google hit for me. Anyway, did it work for you?

Comment: @DanOvidiuBoncut So your client has a skype plugin and you want to disable the plugin for him/her in your website? Why you even touch user expected behavior?

Comment: i dont want to disable the plugin. i just don't want that icon to appear because it ruins my design. and i made id. i'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that my question is duplicated but that answer don't work for me for some reason. I managed to disable the icon by puttin a html comment in it.

```
555-<!---->409.1115.
```

Comment: That is one of the answers to the duplicate question.