# How to aviod skype detecting values as phone numbers?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, skype

I have a problem of removing skype detecting values as phone numbers and highlighting them if a user has installed a skype plugin.

There are several other questions with this but none of the provided answers work (anymore?):
[How to remove skype detecting number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353542/how-to-remove-skype-detecting-number)

[How can i disable Skype icon from my page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934927/how-can-i-disable-skype-icon-from-my-page)

The meta tag solution of adding this is not working:

```
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
```

Also solutions where you insert a HTML comment, an empty or hidden span is not working:

```
11-<span style="display:none;">_</span>3233
11-<span style=""></span>3233
11-<!-- -->3233
```

I am coding for and have tested primarily in Edge and IE11.

So besides the unrealistic solution of getting all users to disable og uninstall the Skype plugin, has anybody found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is a feature in IE and Edge, If user is using Skype or any other application as a primary app that can make a call then it will highlight the phone number in webpage.
If user click on it then it will take you to that app and dial that number for you.
If you want to disable it then there is a group policy for it. User need to set it to enable.

Below are the steps to configure this setting.

(1) Open Run window and type “gpedit.msc”.

(2) Navigate to path below.

Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Internet Settings > Advanced settings > Browsing

[Click Here to check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYtLu.png)

(3) Double click on “Turn off phone number detection” policy.
 [Click Here to check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mJP5.png)

(4) Select the Enabled option.

(5) Click on Apply and Ok to close the dialog.
This policy setting determines whether phone numbers are recognized and turned into hyperlinks, which can be used to invoke the default phone application on the system.
If you enable this policy setting, phone number detection is turned off. Users won't be able to modify this setting.

If you disable this policy setting, phone number detection is turned on. Users won't be able to modify this setting.

If you don't configure this policy setting, users can turn this behavior on or off, using Internet Explorer settings. The default is on.

Regards

Deepak

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But unfurtunatly you are sugesting getting the users to disable the plugin and as stated in the question this it is not a realistic solution when developing an application for multiple users.